# vscode keeps printing path to python and cwd every time I run a script

Tags: visual-studio-code

As title, vscode keeps printing the path to python.exe and cwd every time I run a script. This started happening after I set up a venv and someone on reddit suggested that it was due to the venv. However, it continues to happen outside of the venv.

[image: keeps printing path]

I know that I can do something with code runner but I'd rather understand exactly why this happens and how to stop it without using code runner, as it didn't happen before. Thank you for your time.

I tried setting `"console": "internalConsole"` in launch.json, but it didn't work. I tried setting the interpreter to a different path, no dice.

Comment: this is the way to run/debug your program no matter what directory you leave the terminal, **It will not change**, A lot more people would complain if they not do this, And you also that your program does not run. If you don't want it type the command yourself `python myscript.py` and use the terminal history to repeat

Comment: I'm sorry, I barely understand your response--I'm a total noob! My program runs just fine, as you can see it prints "Hello World". So can you please explain what you mean by "your program does not run"? I tried python myscript.py on the terminal and you're right, it gave me the output without printing the path. However, I don't want to run it like that, I would preferably run it simply by clicking the run button on vscode. It didn't do this before so there must be a way to get it back to how it was.

Comment: read the whole comment, if it works be happy, this is HOW VSC works, if you don't like it use another editor